# Rails and bootstrap - Add HTML tags to a submit button text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form for a like/unlike button using ajax :

```
= form_for like, :html => { :method => :delete}, :remote => true do |f|
= f.submit pluralize(@video.likes.count, 'like'), :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini", "data-disable-with"=> "Just a moment..."
```

The form works perfectly.

I would like to add an icon in front of the text in the submit button. The haml code for adding the icon is the following (twitter bootstrap) :

```
%i.icon-heart.icon-white
```

Is there a way to add this html to the button? I tried adding it as plain html, but rails rendered it as text.

**UPDATE**

I have manage to encapsulate the submit button in a span class which contains the icon and the appropriate styling. I now need to remove every styling on the button...

```
%span.btn.btn-danger.btn-mini
  %i.icon-heart.icon-white
  = f.submit pluralize(@video.likes.count, 'like')
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Thanks to ismaelga, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form).

This is the solution :

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
 <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
<% end %>
```

Comment: Even if this solution works, I don't like it because I can't see the f variable anymore :) Feels like submitting a form out of nowhere...

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. The question was to add html to the button "text" part of a form_for form builder helper, not reversing your steps into the manual button_tag view helper method. You should have used 
`f.button type: :button, class: 'your_classes', { haml code here }`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer for the question itself will work but is more like a patch instead of the perfect solution keeping code style clear and consistent. It backtracks into using the standard and manual view method:  `#button_tag`. I tend to avoid those manual methods like #submit_tag, #form_tag, #input_tag ... etc because they are unrelated to the backed model or form-model itself and you need to manually do everything on them. Even though the submit has no connection with the `f.` that every input in a `form_for` has like for e.g. `f.input ...`, it's about style, code readability and good programming practices. This code works perfectly fine (form_for and simple_form):

```
= f.button :button, type: :submit, class: 'class1 class2 ... classN' do
    = 'button call to action text'
    %i.fa.fa-download.ml5 // => haml icon as requested
```

Hope it helps others reaching this post like me trying to avoid `_tag` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be `button` in place of `submit`

see Rails documentation [FormBuilder#button](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-button)

```
= f.button :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini" do
  %i.icon-heart.icon-white
    = pluralize(@video.likes.count, 'like')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I haven't tested but I think it's possible to do something like this.

```
= f.submit :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini", "data-disable-with"=> "Just a moment..." do
  %i.icon-heart.icon-white
  = pluralize(@video.likes.count, 'like')
end
```

So this was possible if you where using simple_form. I'm sorry.

So another try would be

```
= f.submit "#{pluralize(@video.likes.count, 'like')} <i class='icon-heart icon-white'/>".html_safe, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini", "data-disable-with"=> "Just a moment..."
```

Comment: I tried install SimpleForm and using your first answer, but it does not work. Your second neither..

Comment: Ah! Thanks to your answer, I found new keywords to search Google! [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form) was really helpful!

Comment: I also answered that question :) Hope you can find a solution

Comment: Thanks to you, I did find an answer :) This problem has been buggin me for a while!

Comment: f.submit wont work, you need f.button with type submit and a block as last argument to output custom haml/html

Answer (score 2):

Justin D's answer helped me also. If you're coming here from Google and you're looking for a Slim implementation, you can do it like this:

```
= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-default') do
    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-floppy-disk>
    | Save
end
```

Slim users will recognize the `>`'s necessity.

This worked for me with Rails 4.1.5, Ruby 2.1.2, and bootstrap-sass 3.2 as of September 24, 2014.

Comment: This saved me hours of frustration.  +1!

Answer (score 0):

Soluction

```
= button_to('Add', line_item_path, method: :post , class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg" , params: { param1: 'value1',  param2: 'value2' })
```

http://qiita.com/tomomomo1217/items/a5f790c31670587e2d87

[How to place an image inside of a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117191/how-to-place-an-image-inside-of-a-link/32030708#32030708)

Answer (score -3):

Please try the below code .  It works

```
<%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success btn-mini" %>
```

Comment: It would be great to add some explanation.

Comment: Your answer doesn't include the html within the submit tag, so it doesn't include the icon.

Comment: This does not answer the question