# How to place an image inside of a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, slim-lang

I'm trying something really simple, inside a link I want there to be text and an image.

```
= link_to 'NVidia Graphics', inventory_url, class: 'lato' do
  = image_tag 'list-highlighter.png'
```

I'd like the output to be something like:

```
<a href="/inventory">
  NVidia Graphics
  <img src="list-highlighter.png" />
</a>
```

How can I achieve this using Slim? My current code causes the website to crash.

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for "http://foobar.com/inventory":String

Answer (score 10):

```
= link_to inventory_url, class: 'lato' do
  | NVidia Graphics
  = image_tag 'list-highlighter.png'
```

I think that should work.. just not 100% about the slim syntax. `link_to` shouldn't have any content when wrapping something as a block -- that is, it should be immediately followed by its url. All the content inside will be wrapped by the `<a>` tag output. For non-slim, this would look like

```
<%= link_to inventory_url, class: 'lato %>
  NVidia Graphics
  <%= image_tag 'list-highlighter.png' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Soluction

```
= button_to('Add', line_item_path, method: :post , class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg" , params: { param1: 'value1',  param2: 'value2' })
```

Rendered

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/line_items/17">
<input class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" type="submit" value="Add" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Qk2sdfgasdfasdfsfa sdfsfsw==" />
<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />
<input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value1" />
</form>
```

http://qiita.com/tomomomo1217/items/a5f790c31670587e2d87