# Substitute a Rails form submit button by a Bootstrap icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, icons, many-to-many

I have an app in which users and groups are linked by a many-to-many relationship.

I have a join table GroupUsers, and I would like to enable an user to add or remove a group from his directly in the group index, which is displayed as a table.

To add a group, I have added a form in one of the column of the index that creates a GroupUser entity. The problem is, I would like to use a Bootstrap icon-plus-sign to submit the form (the user_id and group_id are in hidden fields).

My column looks like this (in slim, `.` is substitute for `class=` in HTML parts) :

```
td
  = form_for @item, as: :group_user, url: "groups/#{group.id}/users" do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
    = f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => group.id
    .form-actions
      = f.submit '' do 
        i.icon-plus-sign.icon.icon-large
```

For the moment, instead of only a plus sign I get an empty button in the table, what shall I do ?

PS: I've checked this answer: [Add icon to submit button in twitter bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376192/add-icon-to-submit-button-in-twitter-bootstrap-2), which includes a bootstrap icon inside the button, but I want to have the icon instead of the button.

Comment: You can't have icon instead of the button. Otherwise you won't be able to submit form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by `bronislav` you won't be able to submit your form without having a button. If you only want to display an image then i think in your case it'll be better to use an `image` of *+ icon* and then you can use rails `image_submit_tag`. You can have

```
= f.image_submit_tag("icon.png")
# => <input alt="Login" src="/images/icon.png" type="image" />
```

For more information refer [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag)

**OR**

You can do something like from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604304/rails-and-bootstrap-add-html-tags-to-a-submit-button-text):

```
=button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do
  %i.icon-plus-sign.icon.icon-large
```

Comment: Thank you, it's still not what I want (it looks terrible with image_submit_tag), but I know I can't do it now. By the way, `f.image_submit_tag` won't work, nor will `f.image_submit`, only `image_submit_tag` is accepted.

Comment: @user284130 If you are talking about image being terrible then you can use a [2x image](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2012/creating-retina-images-for-your-website/) that will make it look better.

Comment: That's not the problem, it creates a button that is something like 4 times higher than a table lign, whatever the size of the image is.
**EDIT** : I believe it's not a button, but the form itself.

Comment: @user284130 You can give it a class and then adjust its width and height accordingly, that's more of a  css and tables problem not rails :)

Comment: Just figured it out ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

With HAML you need to do something like this:

```
= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-success') do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
```

or with ERB

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-success') do %>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit button needs to be a `button[type=submit]` with the icon inside of it. `<input type=submit />` elements cannot have node children, and therefore you cannot have an `<i>` element inside of it.

The HTML should look like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-plus-sign icon icon-large"></i>
</button>
```

EDIT: In slim, I believe it would look like:

```
= content_tag :button, :type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn.primary' do
  i.icon-plus-sign.icon.icon-large
```