# How to use an image for buttons in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form_for in my rails project that allows a user to upload a file and then click submit. As of now they are standard buttons. I would like to use an icon image for the "choose your file" button. Is there a way to keep the functionality of that button, but instead make it an image that the user can click on to upload their file?

```
    <%= form_for@user, :url => users_upload_path, multipart: true, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :name %> <%= f.submit %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.submit "Comment", :type => :image, :src => "/images/comment-button.png" %>
```

OR

```
<%= image_submit_tag("login.png") %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag

try this

Comment: It does work for the submit button (thank you for your help). I plan to use CSS to style the submit button so was wondering if it is possible to do this with the choose file button instead?

Comment: This question will help you do that in the way that @test is showing you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604304/rails-and-bootstrap-add-html-tags-to-a-submit-button-text