# How to show a twitter bootstrap icon in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

If I try to use bootstrap's icon class, it doesn't show correctly.
Anyone knows how to display it?

```
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :value => sanitize('<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> ') +  'Create!' if @community.new_record? %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glyphicon-halflings-white.png` (for white icons) must be in the Rails app's `app/assets/images` directory. Then add `<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>` to your desired view.

To use the icon as a form submit button, pass a block to `button_tag`:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

Sources:

- ["Add HTML tags to a submit button text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604304/add-html-tags-to-a-submit-button-text)
- ["HTML code inside buttons with simple_form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form)

Comment: Thanks. Everything is set. Then I've been using this. I just want to know how to use icon in this situation:)

Comment: You mean use the icon as a form submit button? Here are two relavent SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604304/add-html-tags-to-a-submit-button-text and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form