# Rails 4 - Bootstrap themes and crazy CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails 4 app.

I've been struggling for MONTHS to figure out how to incorporate a bootstrap theme. I thought using a design template might help me structure my content, but it is causing me a world of pain. I just can't figure out how to work with it.

Everything has been incorporated into the pipeline, but now I have instances of CSS that isn't in my code, being imposed.

For example, in my new user registration form, I have a submit button that has:

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", :class=>'btn btn-info' %>
</div>
```

The info button is blue. When I load the page, it shows with now background colour.

When I load localhost and inspect the element, I get this:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-default btn btn-info">
```

The btn btn-default is not part of my code, but somehow it is being imposed.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem. I've torn my hair out for weeks trying to figure this out.

MORE INFO:

When I inspect the code, it shows the attributes of btn btn-info as struck out. I understand this to mean that a closer CSS tag has overridden that element, but the tag that inserts that CSS tag is the last in the list. How can there be anything closer? And if there is something, why doesn't it show in the inspector?

Comment: Have you checked whether this is coming from the output HTML or being applied in JavaScript? Has the theme got custom JavaScript that could be applying this?

Comment: I don't know how to check any of these things

Comment: Are you using Simple Form (or any other form helper) as questioned in @Stan's answer? If so then your problem may lie there. If you are not then my question is, you say you have imported lots of code from the theme into your pipeline, is any of that performing any custom behaviour that overrides what you expect?

Comment: I use Simple Form. Prior to incorporating the theme, my styling css worked fine. Now its overridden and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I have no idea why people down vote this post. It doesnt tell me a thing about why they don't like it. My problem has not been resolved and all it does is compound confusion. I think if people want to down vote - that's fine - but it would be constructive to leave a note explaining why. If anyone has help to solve this problem - I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the HTML response before any JavaScript is executed? You can use `curl` to make the request on the command line or use your web browser by disabling JavaScript before refreshing the page. The first step to knowing where the interference is coming from is by knowing which side (server or client) to look.

Comment: Thanks @R.Hatherall. I'll do some research into how to use the curl command to investigate this possibility. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As a quick work-around (rough fix), you may update .btn-default CSS style for element under .form-actions form. Either use it that way, or designate a new class for specific form (e.g. <div class="special-form-actions">, and then put things in your .css - e.g. .special-form-actions .btn-default { /* some css styles */ }

Comment: As another quick hack, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858582/html-code-inside-buttons-with-simple-form) response of using button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary")  instead of f.button, it shouldn't generate extra css class to your HTML output.

Comment: As for downvotes, it might be connected with the fact of stating that you struggle for months with web deb and specifically bootstrap, and it still looks like you can't figure out what's happening with html and css styles ("How can there be anything closer?"). Would you consider passing some [base](https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript) course on HTML principles to speed up? no offense

Comment: @PavelBulanov - thanks very much for all the help Pavel. I've actually been trying to learn for almost 4 years. I've done several coursera courses on frontend, db design, ops and rails. I'm struggling with all of it. I have loads of books, tutorials and resources, but the things I don't understand seems to be fundamental (and not explained in the materials I have). I'll try the course you recommended. Thanks very much again

Comment: @Mel I too bought a bootstrap theme thinking it would be easy-peasy to get it going in my Rails 5 app. Nothing of the sort. I can't even get all the friggin asset pieces into the pipeline. How did you get it set up.
My theme has (css, fonts, images, js, scss)  assets folders. The scss one has a couple of subfolders. I'm STUCK!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using simple_form ? If so, take a look in your `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` (or `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` if you used the flag `--bootstrap` at the generation, which I think you did)

By default, Simple Form apply a specific wrapper (see [documentation here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)  to make your own).

If you just need this one button, either way, you have to specify it like so :

```
<%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'btn btn-info' } %>
```

You have the same helper for the generated label :

```
<%= f.input :username, label_html: { class: 'my_class' } %>
```

Now, for a button, apparently doing simply this should do the trick (according to the documentation):

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Custom Button Text", class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

Don't hesitate to have a look at the (well made) documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) (once again, assuming you use Simple Form :-) )

Comment: I tried the first suggestion. It doesnt work. The button is still invisible. When I inspect the code, it has: <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" input_html="{:class=>"btn btn-info"}" class="btn btn-default">

Comment: Also @Stan I use Simple Form.

Comment: My bad. Looks like what I described was for inputs. I added an update at the end of the answer.

Comment: Hi @Stan, unfortunately the last suggestion on your edited answer didn't work either. Taking that suggestion, when I save and refresh, the code inspector shows: <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-info">

Comment: Then it's working :) You see the "btn-info" has been added. As I said in my answer, check in your wrapper definition in your `initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`. Clean up unwanted classes added to submit button here. Don't forget to restart the server after as you modified an initializer, which is only loaded at server start.

Comment: No. It isn't working. I have checked my initialiser and I changed it from info to primary just to see if it did anything. I creates the same problem but with primary where info was.  I restarted the server before checking the outcome. I can't see how this solves any problem since the unidentified source of the interference of an undefined class is isn't solved. It's so frustrating, but this definitely isn't solved

Comment: @Mel, So if you check simple_form_bootstrap.rb in your initializers and remove btn-default class from SimpleForm.setup do |config|  config.button_class = 'btn btn-default' .. -> what happens then? [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/ac63da0f0b38df82385493f25f649e320b0acb4a/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb) is the original config file created by simple form generator

Comment: The config value is added to button classes here - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/6f537ed98e0fb7a50977a101d1da92dc0696031e/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L213 - I don't see easy way to remove this class output for single specific control. Either remove it globally or override selectors for this style in your case

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1307) - you can't individually remove btn-default class - need to remove it in general config file if you need

Comment: @PavelBulanov I replaced button_class in the initialiser with :config.button_class = 'formsubmit' and wrote my own css to make it look like a button. It now works to display a button and when I inspect element on the chrome inspector it doesnt impose additional css overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Check simple_form_bootstrap.rb in your initializers and remove 'btn-default' class from

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config| config.button_class = 'btn btn-default'
```

Use e.g. your own style there - if you want it applied for all buttons. Alternatively, make this option an empty string and apply individual specific classes for each separate button:

```
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-specific" %>
```

The config value is added to button classes [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/6f537ed98e0fb7a50977a101d1da92dc0696031e/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L213)

I don't see easy way to remove this class output for single specific control. Either remove it globally or override selectors for this style in your case.

See [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1307) - you can't individually remove btn-default class - need to remove it in general config file if you need